# background-image don't work in div element

Tags: html, css

Don't work background-image  in div with class nav-item. All images are in the same directory. Background in header works. And with img src everything is good. Where is the problem?

I tried everything.

```css
header {
    background: url('backSmall2.png');
    height: 670px;
}
 
img {
    width: 14%;
    transform:skewY(-1deg);
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    box-shadow:  0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
 
.nav-item {
    width: 12%;
    background-image: url('frame.png');
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 140px;
}
 
.logo-contacts {
    background-image: url('frame.png');
}
 
.contacts {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="normalize.css" rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="index-style.css" rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="logo1.png">
            <div class="nav-item"></div>
            <a href="#contacts" class="logo-contacts"> </a>
        </header>
        <a name="contacts">
            <div class="contacts">
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your `background-image` some more information about position.

For example:

```
.nav-item {
    width: 12%;
    background-image: url('frame.png');
    background-position: center; /* Added */
    background-size: cover; /* Added */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Added */
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 140px;
}
```

Read more about the `background` property at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `div` is empty - So - it has no height. Try adding height to the CSS class:

```
.nav-item {
    width: 12%;
    background-image: url('frame.png');
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    height: XXXpx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!-- language: lang-css -->

    header {
       background: url('backSmall2.png');
       height: 670px;
   }

  img {
       width: 14%;
      transform:skewY(-1deg);
       margin-top: 40px;
       margin-left: 40px;
       box-shadow:  0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
       transform: rotate(-3deg);
    }

   .nav-item {
       width: 600px;
      height:600px;
    background-image: url('frame.png');
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 140px;
}

.logo-contacts {
    background-image: url('frame.png');
}

.contacts {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="normalize.css" rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="index-style.css" rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="logo1.png">
            <div class="nav-item"></div>
            <a href="#contacts" class="logo-contacts"> </a>
        </header>
        <a name="contacts">
            <div class="contacts">
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```